# Not sure why I'm getting an error when setting a UILabel as hidden | Swift

Tags: swift, boolean, uilabel, hidden

I have a function that checks if the user has access to the photo library. I am trying to set a `PhotoAccessLabel` as hidden. I am getting the error:

> Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly
>   unwrapping an Optional value

I am new to Swift and am simply editing a file created by a peer. Any tips on what is going wrong?

```swift
func photoPermissionAccepted() {
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        if self.allassets == nil || self.allassets.count <= 0 {
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.permissionLabel.isHidden = false
            }
            self.PhotoAccessLabel.isHidden = true

        } else {
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.permissionLabel.isHidden = true
            }
        }

    }
}
func photoPermissionDenied() {
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.PhotoAccessLabel.isHidden = false
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you add permission to the photo library in the info.plist?

Comment: Maybe `self.PhotoAccessLabel` is `nil`. Maybe `self.permissionLabel` is `nil`. How do we know? You are the one running the code. Look and see.

Comment: Hi Thomas, If permissionLabel and PhotoAccessLabel are IBOutlets make sure you have linked them to the proper file owner in your Storyboard. If not, they will be nil when you try to modify them and cause the crash

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fatal error: *unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value* appears the most when you have declared an @IBOutlet, but not connected to the storyboard. Please check both the outlet connections for *PhotoAccessLabel* & *permissionLabel*.